# Compiling js files over to another directory isn't working as intended

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my tsconfig.json file

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "watch": false,
        "target": "ES2020",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "ES2020",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": false,
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.*",
        "src/json/.env"
    ]
}
```

Basically I want that the js files end up in `dist/index.js` and not in `dist/src/index.js`

This is how it ends up

[image: Compilation ouput in dist image]

This is how I want it to be

[image: how i want files to be image]

What should I change and why?

Comment: Looks like it _should_ be doing what you want but you could also try adding `"rootDir": "./src"`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir

Answer (score 1):

Update tsconfig.json as below

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "watch": false,
        "target": "ES2020",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "ES2020",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "rootDir": "./src", /** Specifies the root directory of input files */
    }
}
```

The compiler looks at your tsconfig.json and finds all the files it needs to build by looking at `"files"/"includes"/"excludes"` then following all `///<reference .. />` and `import` statements.. now it has a transitive closure of all files it needs to build. you can use tsc --listFiles to see the list.

The next step is generating the output. for every input file (i.e. a `.ts/.tsx` file) it needs to generate an matching output (a `.js`.jsx file). To figure out the file path of the generated output file it will chop off the "rootDir" from the input, then prepend the "outDir" to it.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25646

Comment: There is a json file outside the src folder i need to not copy, can i make the compiled version use that one? because it gives me an error that tells me that the file is outside rootDir